# FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo does not respect File System Redirection

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems, io-redirection

I have an x86 C#.Net application running on an x64 OS (Windows 2008 R2 in this case). I am trying to check the file version of my.DLL in System32, but it keeps getting the version of my.DLL in SysWow64, even though I am disabling File System Redirection.

Here is the stripped down code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(IntPtr ptr);
....
string myDLL = "c:\\windows\\system32\\my.dll";
IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr();
Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref ptr);
var ver = new Version(FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(myDLL).FileVersion);
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("file={0} ver={1}", myDLL, ver));
Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(ptr);
```

It always shows the version of my.dll in SysWow64. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Is the WOW really getting the version number?  You aren't setting the pointer to a dll filename. Does my.dll really exist in the system32 folder?  Try putting your dll in a folder other than system32.  I'm not sure but I suspect any dll in the system32 folder has to be registered for the GetVersionInfo to work.

Comment: You can access the 64-bit file without messing with the file system redirection using `c:\windows\sysnative\my.dll`.

Comment: It works just fine.  Easier to test by using a file that is only available in system32, like fhsvcctl.dll.  Could be just naming confusion, system32 is for 64-bit executables, syswow64 is for 32-bit executables.  Could be that the process runs in 64-bit mode, paying too much attention to the solution platform name is a very traditional mistake.  Only the EXE project's Project > Properties > Build tab settings matter.  In general never do this, Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection() is very dangerous in a C# app since you can never be sure exactly when the CLR loads a DLL.

Comment: @jdweng - yes, my.dll exists is both System32 and SysWow64, but with different version numbers. That is how I know it is getting the x86 DLL.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Using SysNative did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I'd still like to understand why FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo didn't work with Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection.

Comment: You'd probably have to look at the reference source to see what's going on there.  Possibly .NET is deliberately turning redirection back on, or perhaps the underlying file handle has already been cached somehow, or is being opened in a different thread.

Comment: Any idea where I would find the reference source?  I searched the whole disk.